# st_* in r gives a blank list when tried to intersect polygons and points

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I have one dataframe (`coor` ) with variety of info like latitude (`latitud`) in one column and longitude (`longitud`) in another one, so built points with the combination of both columns:

```
coor$point <- data.frame(coor$latitud, coor$longitud) %>%
  as.matrix() %>% st_multipoint() %>% st_sfc() %>% st_cast("POINT")
st_crs(coor$point) <- st_crs(interest$isochrone)
coor$point <- st_geometry(coor$point)
```

Also got a second data frame (`interest`) that is a subset of observations from `coor` but with the isochrone coordinates for the selected observations. If I use st_intersects() to get the points in `coor` that intersects the isochrones in `interest` it results on lists of length 0 with no points, not even the same point that was used to get the isochrone, here is the code:

```
st_intersects(interest$isochrone,
                    coor$point)
```

But when I run the intersect with the same column it does give the correct results, both columns `isochrone` and `point` are class `sfc`. I will be very thankful if someone can help me

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, without any reproducible samples (`dput()`) it is near impossible to help. Second, your code seems quite redundant/complex for no good reason. A simple `st_sf/st_as_sf` would suffice to make a point column. And third, my best guess of what you show, is that you try to intersect a point layer with a line which will only yield a result if you have a perfect match of overlapping coordinates. Maybe creating a buffer around your line is what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @D.J ! Thanks for your welcome and advice, how do I input the reproducible sample? Copy the (`dput()` ) output here? Or can I upload the .txt?

Comment: yes you can just copy the dput-output as code snippet into your question.